# Email Tab in Lightning Experience for Opportunity object

Tags: lightning, email, opportunity, lightning-experience, activities

For the record type standard in Opportunity Object, there's an email tab. But for the other record types, there's no email tab.

Here's the picture:
[image]
**STANDARD RECORD TYPE**

[image]
**CUSTOM RECORD TYPE**

How can we display the email tab for the opportunity record page in lightning for all record types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email tab/button is defined in the page layout, so you need to define for each record type's page layout the email button:

1. on each page layout click `Salesforce1 & LIghtning Actions`:

[image]

2. Drag And drop the `Email` button to the `Salesforce1 & LIghtning Actions` section:

[image]

3. Save and assign correctly the page layouts to your profiles and record types